# How to make element lose its animation slowly?

Tags: html, css

i.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="move"><div class="move2">Hello</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
@keyframes moving{
    from{transform: translateX(0px);}
    to{transform: translateX(50px);}
}

.move:hover .move2{
    animation: moving 2s ease forwards;
}
```

When I hover over Hello , it moves 50px to the right very smoothly , but I want for it to come back slowly in case I move the pointer from it , when it is no longer hovering. I don't want it to snap right back into its place when hover is removed. How do I do that?
When I hover over Hello , it moves 50px to the right very smoothly , but I want for it to come back slowly in case I move the pointer from it , when it is no longer hovering. I don't want it to snap right back into its place when hover is removed.
How do I do that?

Comment: Use a `transition` not an animation

Comment: @paulie_D it does the same thing, when I remove mouse , it comes back snaping.

Comment: The animation as you have it set up moves the hello (snapping motion) back while you are still hovering. Do you want it to not move the hello back until you stop hovering or do you want it to move right for 2seconds then  immediately back for 2 seconds?

Comment: @AHaworth The animation happens for 2 secs , in case  I remove the pointer from it before 2 secs , I dont want it to quickly jump it to its original position.

Answer (score 0):

Using transition on transforms it is possible to ensure that there is no 'jumping' when the element returns to its initial position.

To achieve this we need to set the transition on the element, not just on the hovered element.

```css
.move .move2 {
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: all 2s;
}

.move:hover .move2 {
  transform: translateX(50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="move">
  <div class="move2">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @AHaworth . I tried it and thanks, it works. Could you please tell me what was I doing wrong and why your solution worked?

Comment: my issue still persists though , because I had to perform many transforms when I hover over the element (like rotate multiple times as well as translate ) which I can only do if I use animations.

Comment: Answer to your first question: because the transformation going back to the non hover state also obeys the transition. For your second comment, there probably needs to be a more complex example code in your question as I just answered the practical situation presented. Sounds like we need to know more of the context.

Comment: yeah I figured that I have to use JS , I was trying tp avoid it , bit I've managed . Thanks again.